# How to track memory usage using EASTL?

Tags: c++, stl, eastl

The Electronic Arts [EASTL](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL) library's `east::allocator` requires the user to implement a special `new` operator (as shown in this [sample](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/doc/SampleNewAndDelete.cpp)). This `new` operator has a `const char* name`, which is supposed to be used to log application-specific information about memory **allocations** performed EASTL containers. The EASTL [Best Practices](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/doc/EASTL%20Best%20Practices.html) guide also mentions that one should "*Name containers to track memory usage.*"

However, there does not appear to be any corresponding `const char* name` passed by `eastl::allocator::deallocate`, so there does not appear to be a built-in way to log memory **deallocations**.

How is this EASTL debugging functionality intended to be used? I think I  must be missing something. An EA Software Engineer also gave a related [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KIvWJUYbDA) in 2015, where he showed some internal tools developed by EA for memory debugging, and it seems to suggest that they tracking both allocations and deallocations (for example, to ensure that the memory for "game level 1" is freed when "game level 2" begins).

Comment: For example, the allocator could allocate a block larger than requested, stash the name (and/or any additional information) at the beginning, and return a pointer to the remaining part of the block. Deallocator would then find this information at the negative offset from the pointer it is given.

Answer (score 1):

The allocators by the EASTL are stateful and bound to the instance of the container; meaning they are defined at instance level:

> What EASTL does is use a more familiar memory allocation pattern
>   whereby there is only one allocator class interface and it is used by
>   all containers. Additionally EASTL containers let you access their
>   allocators and query them, name them, change them, etc.
>
> EASTL has chosen to make allocators not be copied between containers
>   during container swap and assign operations. This means that if
>   container A swaps its contents with container B, both containers
>   retain their original allocators. Similarly, assigning container A to
>   container B causes container B to retain its original allocator.
>   Containers that are equivalent should report so via operator==; EASTL
>   will do a smart swap if allocators are equal, and a brute-force swap
>   otherwise.

from https://github.com/questor/eastl/blob/master/doc/EASTL%20Design.html

So I would add a member to the allocator class and track the memory count inside it, like following:

```
#ifndef EASTL_CUSTOM_ALLOCATOR_H_
#define EASTL_CUSTOM_ALLOCATOR_H_

#include "new_implementation.hpp"
#include <EASTL/list.h>
#include <iostream>

#define DEBUG_MACRO

class EASTL_CustomAllocator {
public:
    EASTL_CustomAllocator(const char* pName = EASTL_NAME_VAL(EASTL_ALLOCATOR_DEFAULT_NAME))
        : m_pName(pName), m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated(0) {
#ifdef DEBUG_MACRO
        std::cout << m_pName << ": default construct allocator" << std::endl;
#endif
    }
    EASTL_CustomAllocator(const EASTL_CustomAllocator& x)
        : m_pName(x.m_pName),
          m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated(x.m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated) {
#ifdef DEBUG_MACRO
        std::cout << m_pName << ": copy construct allocator" << std::endl;
#endif
    }
    EASTL_CustomAllocator(const EASTL_CustomAllocator& x, const char* pName)
        : m_pName(pName),
          m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated(x.m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated) {
#ifdef DEBUG_MACRO
        std::cout << m_pName << ": copy construct allocator" << std::endl;
#endif
    }

    EASTL_CustomAllocator& operator=(const EASTL_CustomAllocator& x) {
#ifdef DEBUG_MACRO
        std::cout << m_pName << ": copy assignment" << std::endl;
#endif
        m_pName = x.m_pName;
        m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated = x.m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated;
        return *this;
    }

    void* allocate(size_t num_of_bytes, int flags = 0) {
        m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated += num_of_bytes;
        void* p = ::new((char*)0, flags, 0, (char*)0,        0) char[num_of_bytes];
#ifdef DEBUG_MACRO
        std::cout << m_pName << ": allocate " << num_of_bytes << " bytes" << " at: " << (void*) p << std::endl;
#endif
        return p;
    }
    void* allocate(size_t num_of_bytes, size_t alignment, size_t offset, int flags = 0) {
        m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated += num_of_bytes;
        void* p = ::new(alignment, offset, (char*)0, flags, 0, (char*)0,        0) char[num_of_bytes];
#ifdef DEBUG_MACRO
        std::cout << m_pName << ": allocate " << num_of_bytes << " bytes" << " at: " << (void*) p << std::endl;
#endif
        return p;
    }
    void  deallocate(void* p, size_t num_of_bytes) {
        m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated -= num_of_bytes;
#ifdef DEBUG_MACRO
        std::cout << m_pName << ": deallocate " << num_of_bytes << " bytes" << " at: " << (void*) p << std::endl;
#endif
        delete[](char*)p;
    }

    const char* get_name() const {
        return m_pName;
    }
    void        set_name(const char* pName) {
        m_pName = pName;
    }
    size_t get_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated() const {
        return m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated;
    }

protected:
    const char* m_pName;    // Debug name, used to track memory.
    size_t m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated;   // keeps track of the memory currently allocated
};


bool operator==(const EASTL_CustomAllocator& a, const EASTL_CustomAllocator& b) {
    if (&a == &b) {
        return true;    // allocator a and b are equal if they are the same
    }
    else {
        return false;   // otherwhise, return false, because the state m_totalAmountOfBytesAllocated needs to be increased/decreased on splice and swap
    }
}
bool operator!=(const EASTL_CustomAllocator& a, const EASTL_CustomAllocator& b) {
    return false;
}


#endif /* EASTL_CUSTOM_ALLOCATOR_H_ */
```

Pass that custom allocator type as a template parameter to a eastl container like following (also you can set a instance with a user-defined name at construction and even later by set_allocator()):

```
eastl::list<int, EASTL_CustomAllocator> 
list(EASTL_CustomAllocator("EASTL Some Name"));
```

But I'm not sure how the debugging functionality is intended to be used.